# Vocabulary question: am I doing a micro-service or just SOA?

Tags: microservices, soa

Let's say I have several monolithic web applications. In each of them, the same type of business data must be found according to certain parameters, or according to the application itself. I therefore repeat the same logic everywhere, which in my case is tedious.

I therefore wish to develop another web application, internal, which will have:

- an administration interface that will allow you to define all the business data recovery scenarios
- REST APIs which will be consumed by my web applications to find the business data according to the incoming scenario

This new application will have its own database, and could possibly be deployed on another server. For convenience, I'm thinking of using the same technologies (in my case, C # + Angular)

Therefore, am I going to develop what is called a micro-service? Or is it better to just talk about a service oriented architecture? Or am I going to do some obscure shenanigans?

Thank you for your attention !

Comment: I think this [SESE post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/356539/what-is-really-different-between-soa-and-microservices) will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's SOA in this case. Because

- Your primary target is enterprise level code/logic sharing which tends to SOA rather than microservice.
- In the case of microservice architecture the services are in granular level that make the application loosely coupled. In your case I don't think you are breaking down each major  functionalities of the application by introducing smaller services that can be used within the application not necessarily across the applications.

For the case of existing applications usually it shouldn't be a one shot process if you want to introduce microservices. You can always gradually breaking the parts into services that make sense to the particular application.

You can have a look at some of the articles -

- [https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/soa-vs-microservices#:~:text=The%20main%20distinction%20between%20the,when%20you%20neglect%20this%20difference](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/soa-vs-microservices#:%7E:text=The%20main%20distinction%20between%20the,when%20you%20neglect%20this%20difference).
- https://www.talend.com/resources/microservices-vs-soa/